# Cant find options which get NIntegrate[] to give an accurate answer

Tags: numerical-integration

I'm trying to numerically evaluate an integral (specifically an integral of a function of an integral), and I cannot find a set of options for `NIntegrate` which results in correct answers. I have tried several things (detailed) below, and would be very grateful for anyone who can help with this problem.

Specifically I want to evaluate, for $p = 1,2$
$$
m_p(b,c) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty dx_1 \int_0^\infty dx_2 f_1(x_1)f_2(x_2)\left(\log \left[g\left(\frac{c\mathrm{e}^{b x_1}}{x_2^2};b,c\right)\right]\right)^p
$$
where 
$$
\begin{aligned}
g\left(y;b,c\right) &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty dx_1 \int_0^\infty dx_2f_1(x_1)f_2(x_2) h\left(y,\frac{c\mathrm{e}^{b x_1}}{x_2^2} \right)
\\
h(y_1,y_2)& = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left( \sqrt{1- \frac{1}{\sqrt{(1 + 4 y_1)(1 + 4 y_2)}}} +  \sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{(1 + 4 y_1)(1 + 4 y_2)}}} \right)
\\
f_1(x) &= \tfrac12 f_2(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \mathrm{e}^{-x^2/2} 
\end{aligned}
$$
code for this is provided below

```
f1[x_] := 1/Sqrt[2 π] Exp[-x^2/2];
f2[x_] := 2 f1[x];
h[y1_, y2_] := 
 1/Sqrt[2] (Sqrt[1 - 1/(Sqrt[1 + 4 y1] Sqrt[1 + 4 y2])] + Sqrt[
    1 + 1/(Sqrt[1 + 4 y1] Sqrt[1 + 4 y2])]);
g[y_, b_, c_] := 
 NIntegrate[
  f1[x1] f2[x2] h[y, (c Exp[x1 b])/
    x2^2], {x1, -∞, ∞}, {x2, 0, ∞}]
m1[b_, c_] := 
 NIntegrate[
  f1[x1] f2[x2] Log[
    g[(c Exp[x1 b])/x2^2, b, 
     c]], {x1, -∞, ∞}, {x2, 0, ∞}]
m2[b_, c_] := 
 NIntegrate[
  f1[x1] f2[
    x2] (Log[
     g[(c Exp[x1 b])/x2^2, b, 
      c]])^2, {x1, -∞, ∞}, {x2, 0, ∞}]
```

Consider for example the arguments

```
b=0.05;
c=0.05;
```

from the structure of the integral we know that $m_2(b,c) - m_1(b,c)^2$ is a variance, and so is strictly non-negative. Moreover, as the integrand is not constant, and the distributions $f_1, f_2$ not sharply peaked we know it is positive. However evaluating the functions always returns

```
In[]:= m2[b,c] - m1[b,c]^2

Out[]= -1.64707*10^-9
```

However from other means (details in appendix below) we know that
$$
m_2(b,c) - m_1(b,c)^2 > 0.014
$$

I have looked through the suggestion on this site, but nothing I found yet worked. Things I have tried:

- Different combinations of `_?NumericQ` flags on the arguments, including all arguments, the `y, y1, y2` arguments only, and no arguments.
- Forcing recursions using `MinRecursion -> 1` and `MinRecursion -> 2`
- Changing method to `Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", Method -> "ClenshawCurtisRule"}`
- Changing variables in the integrals to $x= \sqrt{2}(\mathrm{Erf}^{-1}(2 t-1)$ which takes the domain of integration from $(-\infty,\infty) \times (0,\infty)$ to $(0,1) \times (\tfrac12,1)$.
- Changing variables to $x_2 = \mathrm{e}^{-z/2}$ to simplify structure of integral.

#### Appendix

In evidence of the above claims we can show that 
$$
\begin{aligned}
m_p(b,c) &= \int_0^\infty dy f_3(y) \, \left(\log \left[g\left(y;b,c\right)\right]\right)^p
\\
f_3(y) & = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} d x_1 f_1(x_1) f_2 \left( \sqrt{\frac{c}{y}} \mathrm{e}^{b x_1/2} \right) \frac12 \sqrt{\frac{c}{y^3}}\mathrm{e}^{b x_1/2}
\end{aligned}
$$
the code for $f_3$ is

```
f3[y_, b_, c_] := 
 NIntegrate[
  f2[Sqrt[c/y] Exp[(x1 b)/2]] f1[x1] 1/2 Sqrt[c/y^3]
    Exp[(x1 b)/2], {x1, -∞, ∞}]
```

which can be evaluated over a list and plotted yielding the functions plotted below (same plot, just different plot range)

[image: Plots of f_3 and Log g]

from which it is clear that $\log \left[g\left(y;b,c\right)\right]$ varies appreciably over the range of values for which the distribution $f_3(y)$ has significant support, and hence that $m_2(b,c) - m_1(b,c)^2$ is positive. List-integrating these plots we can say 
$$m_2(b,c) - m_1(b,c)^2 > 0.014$$

Comment: I am making slow progress with this - my main take home so far is the ```NIntegrate[]``` can be really sketchy when handed an infinite domain of integration.